# Is there a simpler term that stands for "non-destructive setter"?

Tags: java, oop, terminology, getter-setter

In such a code, `setValue` method is usually called as "setter" in general, but how `withValue` method, (i.e. returns new object whose fields(s) is/are changed), is called in general?

```
class MyClass {
   private int value;
   public MyClass(int value) {this.value=value;}
   // a getter
   public int getValue() {return value;}
   // a (destructive) setter
   public void setValue(int value) {this.value=value;}
   // a (non-destructive) setter <- Is there a simpler term than this? 
   public MyClass withValue(int value) {return new MyClass(value);}
}
```

Comment: Your example of non-destructive setter is not setting anything.

Comment: I sometimes refer to them as "withers" (as in getter, setter, "hazzer" [as in protocol buffer "has"], "izzer" [as in a Boolean is method]). These are not a universally-understod terms, though.

Comment: Also, "withers" is a part of a horse. Stop me if I'm not helping.

Comment: [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The usual prefix for those methods is `with`:

```
MyClass alternateVersion = myClass.withValue(5);
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the method name valueChanged -> withValue.